# Nextjs with Expressjs POST route not found

Tags: express, next.js

I have recently integrated Expressjs with my Nextjs project and was trying to run as POST request to an API.

But I'm getting an error message

> Cannot POST /api/auth/signin/`

I do not receive the same when I make a GET request. Based on the way I integrated ExpressJS from a tutorial, I'm curious if the error message for POST requests stems from not attaching the `.post()` method to the express server in my server side server file. Does this sound like the source of the issue?

**ssr-server.js:**

```js
    const express = require('express')()
    const next = require('next')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    
    // Session Management
    const session = require('express-session')
    const redis = require('redis');
    const redisClient = redis.createClient({
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || 'localhost',
        port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || '6379',
        url: process.env.REDIS_URL || ''
    });
    const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
    
    redisClient.on_connect("error", function(error){
        console.error(error);
    })
    
    const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    const app = next({ dev })
    const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
        
    console.log("Test")
    app.prepare()
    .then(() => {
    
        const server = express()
    
        // Session Management
      server.use(session({
          store: new redisStore({client: redis.RedisClient}),
          secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
          saveUninitialized: false,
          resave: false,
          cookie: {
              secure: process.env.SESSION_SECURE || false,
              httpOnly: true,
          }
      }))
    
    //   Form body parsing
      server.use(bodyParser.json())
      server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
        
      server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res)
      })
        
      server.listen(3000, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
      })
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
      console.error(ex.stack)
      process.exit(1)
    })
```

**/api/auth/signin.js:**

```js
    export default (req, res) => {
        if (req.method === 'POST') {
            if (res.statusCode = 200){
                return res.json({ body: req.body, message: 'Success' })
            } else {
                return res.json({ message: 'Error on POST'})
            }
            
            
        } else {
            return res.json({ message: 'Error' })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `ssr-server.js` lacks a statement like `server.post("/api/auth/signin", require("./api/auth/signin"));` You cannot assume an automatic relationship between URL paths and paths on your server's file system.